# Dockerfile VOLUME not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am really stuck with the usage of docker VOLUME's. I have a plain dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest  
VOLUME /foo/bar
RUN touch /foo/bar/tmp.txt
```

I ran `$ docker build -f dockerfile -t test .` and it was successful. After this, I interactively ran a shell into the docker container associated with the run of the created `test` image. That is, I ran `$ docker run -it test`

**Observations:**

`/foo/bar` is created but **empty**.

`docker inspect test` mounting info:

```
"Volumes": {
  "/foo/bar": {}
}
```

It seems that it is not mounting at all. The task seems pretty straight but am I doing something wrong ?

**EDIT :** I am looking to persist the data that is created inside this mounted volume directory.

Comment: [This is established behavior.](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3639)

Comment: @jwodder , So how to persist data that I create ?

Comment: @user2915097, this is when you do `docker run`, I am talking about dockerfile ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The VOLUME instruction must be placed after the RUN.

As stated in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume :

> Note: If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.

If you want to know the source of the volume created by the docker `run` command:

```
docker inspect --format='{{json .Mounts}}' yourcontainer
```

will give output like this:

```
[{
  "Name": "4c6588293d9ced49d60366845fdbf44fac20721373a50a1b10299910056b2628",
  "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/4c6588293d9ced49d60366845fdbf44fac20721373a50a1b10299910056b2628/_data",
  "Destination": "/foo/bar",
  "Driver": "local",
  "Mode": "",
  "RW": true,
  "Propagation": ""
}]
```

**Source** contains the path you are looking for.

Comment: +1, I've seen odd behavior when volumes are declared early, sometimes they include a single COPY/ADD, but not the result of RUN. Best to put the volume declaration late in the build.

Comment: @michael_bitard , How do I get the mount location on my host disk ?

Comment: @michael_bitard , this seems not to work. I tried it earlier also, can you have a quick look at this : http://imgur.com/Icu4Yne

Comment: @black-perl that's because you are inspecting your image, not your container.

Comment: @michael_bitard, no help still. Used `docker ps` to get container id, here : https://imgur.com/JgX3V35

Comment: @michael_bitard , Thanks btw. I did a docker run and it worked ! Looks like some old container was used.